# Java XML validation does not work when schema comes from classpath

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I am validating XML documents against a schema. Some more complex documents/schemas always fail when trying to validate them using this code:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbfac.setNamespaceAware(true);
    dbfac.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse("sampleResponse.xml");

    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + "SampleResponse.xsd"));

    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaSource);
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
    // Set a custom error handler that simple re-throws every exception
    validator.setErrorHandler(new ValidationErrorHandler());
    validator.validate(source);
```

The problem is this line:

```
    Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + "SampleResponse.xsd"));
```

If I read the schema as a file, it works:

```
    Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(new File("somepath/SampleResponse.xsd"));
```

Why doesn't validation work when I get the schema directly from classpath?

(Using Java 1.6 on Windows 7 64-bit)

Exception message when failing:
`Could not validate against schema SampleResponse.xsd. Nested exception: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'oa:Attachments' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you pass a File to StreamSource, the InputStream is set to the contents of the file, but also the systemId is set to be the URL of the File. This allows relative URIs in your schema to be resolved. If your schema has any relative URLs, this is definitely your problem. To make those relative URLs resolvable when reading the schema from the classpath, you need to implement an [EntityResolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html). If you don't use relative URIs there might still be other more subtle impacts of the systemId being null. I would recommend using the constructor

```
StreamSource(InputStream inputStream, String systemId)
```

Try setting systemId to: null, the File containing the schema, some other file, a File that doesn't exist. That might give you a hint of what Validator is doing with the systemId.

Comment: Yes, the following now works: `Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + "SampleResponse.xsd"), getClass().getResource("/" + "SampleResponse.xsd").toString());` Will it work on all systems?

Comment: I would expect it to work, but I haven't ever tested it. My guess is that it just has to be non-null. I would try setting it to arbitrary values just to demonstrate that the actual value doesn't matter. And I would comment it to make that clear. But I think you have the right idea making it meaningful by using the URI you used to get it from the ClassLoader.

Comment: Lifesaver advice. Setting the systemId solved my problem like magic. Before I was struggling with EntityResolver, without any luck.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I did not need to implement an EntityResolver to make relative URLs resolvable from the classpath.

It was sufficient to set the system id to the URI of the classpath resource.

The following is a worked example that uses Spring to build a list of *StreamSource*s from .xsd files on the classpath.

### Setup validation sources

```java
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource[] theResources = patternResolver.getResources("classpath:schemas/**/*.xsd");
List<Source> sources = new ArrayList<>();
for (Resource resource: theResources) {
    StreamSource dtd = new StreamSource(resource.getInputStream());
    dtd.setSystemId(resource.getURI().toString());
    sources.add(dtd);
```

The *patternResolver* is given a pattern of `classpath:schemas/**/*.xsd` which allows it to recursively find all .xsd files in the *schemas* directory on the classpath.

The .xsd files can import other .xsd files using relative paths. For example a .xsd file could include an import like this:

```
<xsd:import namespace="urn:www.example.com/common" schemaLocation="./common.xsd">
```

This line:

```java
dtd.setSystemId(resource.getURI().toString());
```

is the key to having the relative paths in the .xsd files resolved by the schema validator.

### Perform validation

The *StreamSource* array (*sources*) built above can now be used to set the schema sources for XML validation:

```java
import org.xmlunit.builder.Input;
import org.xmlunit.validation.Languages;
import org.xmlunit.validation.Validator;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;

Validator v = Validator.forLanguage(Languages.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
v.setSchemaSources(sources.toArray(new Source[sources.size()]));
Source input = Input.fromByteArray(xmlBytes).build();
v.validateInstance(input);
```

The *validateInstance* method call validates the XML represented by the *xmlBytes* array.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, here is something I did in Scala, inspired by Joman68's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50518995/434405, that does not use spring libs.

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants
import javax.xml.transform.Source
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
import javax.xml.validation.{Schema, SchemaFactory, Validator}

object SchemaCheck extends App {

  private val xsds = List("schema.xsd") // add more as required

  private val schemaDocuments: Array[Source] = xsds.map { xsd =>
    val res = getClass.getResource(s"/$xsd")
    val dtd = new StreamSource(res.toURI.toString)
    dtd.setSystemId(res.toURI.toString)
    dtd
  }.toArray

  private val sf           = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
  private val s: Schema    = sf.newSchema(schemaDocuments)
  private val v: Validator = s.newValidator()

  private val instanceDocument: Source = new StreamSource(new java.io.File("test.xml"))
  v.validate(instanceDocument)
}
```